# basic example for generating Xml in Django

Tags: python, xml, django

This is my view

```
def Getdata(request):
    data = serializers.serialize("xml", MessageHeaderModel2.objects.all())
    pprint.pprint(data)
    f = open('content.xml', 'w')
    myfile = File(f)
    myfile.write(data)
    myfile.close()
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

the output `127.0.0.1:8000` give this error

```
Exception Value: Expected a character buffer object
```

But the '`data`' output in terminal gives xml output.

Why is the xml not generated in `content.xml` ?

Comment: Why do you have this line: `myfile = File(f)`?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do ? Save XML in a local file or Return in Response ?

Comment: i want save into local file ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not understand why you have this line:

```
myfile = File(f)
```

Its not a python method as far as I know. If you simply want to write the data to a file remove this line:

```
def Getdata(request):
    with open("file.xml", "w") as out:
        xml_serializer.serialize(MessageHeaderModel2.objects.all(), stream=out)
    data = serializers.serialize("xml", MessageHeaderModel2.objects.all())
    pprint.pprint(data)
    return HttpResponse(data)
```